# Rails - Nested includes on Active Records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a list of events that I fetch.
I'm trying to include every user associated to this event and every profile associated to each user. The Users get included but not their profiles.

How Would i do this

```
Event.includes(:users [{profile:}])
```

The docs don't seem to be clear:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score 500, accepted):

I believe the following should work for you.

```
Event.includes(users: :profile)
```

If you want to include an association (we'll call it C) of an already included association (we'll call it B), you'd use the syntax above. However, if you'd like to include D as well, which is also an association of B, that's when you'd use the array as given in the example in the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

```
A.includes(bees: [
  :cees, 
  :dees
])
```

You could continue to nest includes like that (if you actually need to). Say that A is also associated with Z, and that C is associated to E and F.

```
A.includes({
  bees: [{
    cees: [:ees, :effs]
  }, :dees]
}, :zees)
```

And for good fun, we'll also say that E is associated to J and X, and that D is associated to Y.

```
A.includes({
  bees: [{
      cees: [{
        ees: [:jays, :exes]
      }, :effs]
    },
    {
      dees: :wise
    }
  ]
}, :zees)
```

Comment: How would you add conditions for the included modules..? :)

Comment: how to add there a order?

Comment: In the above, we're assuming an event has many users and a user has many profiels right?

Comment: This is one of those magical answers that I have found multiple times years apart and saves my ass every time. This is what the docs should look like

Comment: To make this guide the most exhausting one: `A.includes( { bees: { cees: {:dees, :ees} } })` - for the russian doll like construction (i.e. A includes b, which includes c... and so on)

Comment: to add conditions `A.includes(bees: :cees).where(bees: { cees: { flagged: false }}).order("a.bees DESC").order("a.cees ASC")`

Answer (score 24):

Please refer to Joe Kennedy's solution.

Here's a more readable example (for future me).

```
includes(
  :product,
  :package, {
    campaign: [
      :external_records,
      { account: [:external_records] },
      { agency: [:external_records] },
      :owner,
      :partner,
    ]
  }
)
```

Answer (score 16):

If anyone is doing a `respond_to` block to generate nested json, you can do something like:

```
respond_to do |f|
  f.json do
    render json: event.to_json(include: {users: {include: :profile} }), status: :ok
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you mean `as_json` -- otherwise this renders the JSON string.