# Preload only latest comment to each post in Rails and MySql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, greatest-n-per-group

I have a lot of posts with multiple comments, but I need to show posts with all the information and the latest comment for each post.

With a simple approach that I have an additional request for comments table for each post.

How can I get a list of posts with recent comments without the N+1 problem?

My case is very common - list of posts, with last comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.includes` to eager load objects you know you'll be using.  I think my logic is correct and you'll end up with a unique list of posts where at least one of their comments meets your criteria.

```
def recently_updated_posts    
  comments = Comment.includes(:post).where("updated_at > ?", some_time)
  list_of_posts = posts.comments.map { |c| c.post }
  return list_of_posts.uniq!
end
```

You may be able to reduce the query load further by having a nested includes statement, as silly as it looks:

```
Comment.includes(posts: :comments).where("updated_at > ?", some_time)
```

More here: [Rails - Nested includes on Active Records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397640/rails-nested-includes-on-active-records)

Comment: Thank for info about nesting includes - it's really useful, but in my case I need get posts with and without a comment, and comment must be last, ordered by Id.