# How can I resolve this N+1 query I'm getting with active record query in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I'm having an N+1 query issue with the following active record query...

`@interviews.each do |interview|`

I want to solve it by adding `:college_play_histories` to the active record query through using `.includes(:college_play_histories)`, but currently that association doesn't exist between interviews and college_play_histories. I was going to setup an association between `Interview` and `CollegePlayHistory`, but this seemed incorrect to me and I wasn't sure if there was a way to specify the `college_play_histories` in the includes through `player`.

to
`@interviews.includes(:college_play_history).each do |interview|`

Here are my current models and associations:

**Interview**

```
class Interview < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
end
```

**Player**

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :interviews
  has_many :college_play_histories
end
```

**CollegePlayHistory**

```
class CollegePlayHistory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
end
```

Comment: seems to me `has_many through:..`  will solve it

Comment: which is correct? `has_many through:` or `.includes(player: :college_play_histories)` ? I hesitate on the `has_many through:` because the models are not in my opinion really related in the sense of accessing play histories from interview directly. Hopefully I've conveyed this properly...

Comment: why not use `includes(player: :college_play_histories)`?

Comment: This might come in handy in the future: https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet

Comment: @AbM I was unaware of it before posting the question. I think it is the way to go unless someone can detail otherwise.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24397716/2697183