# Active Record eager load across models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Given the following models, how can I eager load a doctors specialty so I don't get crushed in a loop? Right now I'm able to load the `Doctor` and `User` user models but I'd also like to be able to load their `profiles` and, if possible, the doctors specialty.

```
MedicalRelationship.includes(:doctor, :user).where(user_id: [1,2,3])


class MedicalRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :doctor, :class_name => "User"
end

class DoctorProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :profile, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :specialty
end

class PatientProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :profile, dependent: :destroy
end

class Specialty < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :doctors, class_name: "DoctorProfile"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to load them as follows

```
MedicalRelationship.includes({ doctor: { DoctorProfile: :specialty } }, :user).where(user_id: [1,2,3])
```

as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24397716/1744702) by [Joe Kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2856441/joe-kennedy).

Comment: This would fail if someone have a namespaced class for models. `{ DoctorProfile: :specialty }` would not work. You have to use: `{ doctor_profile: :specialty }`

Answer (score 1):

Active Record lets you `eager load` any number of associations with a single `Model.where/Model.find` call by using an `array`, `hash`, or a `nested hash` of `array/hash` with the `includes` method.

In your case, you can eager load your all the associated models of `MedicalRelationship` using this:

```
MedicalRelationship.includes({ doctor: { doctor_profile: :specialty } }, :user).where(user_id: [1,2,3])
```

I strongly recommend you to read the [Eager Loading Multiple Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) official documentation which explains it with some clear examples.