# Rails load database into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a bunch of tables in my app, and I have a view that basically loads all of them via associations, The problem is I end up with something like 100 queries if its not cached. Is there a way just to do 1 query and load the entire database into memory, I tried .includes but it still does queries for .count and other stuff. .entries doesn't seem to work. Any tips and help are greatly apreciated.

My model associations are like so (many>one, one=one):

- Clients < Projects < Activities = Assignments = Users
- Assignments < Tasks

Comment: Could you provide more information about your schema? You wish to load the entire database? This would be all of the tables and all of their associations?

Comment: edited the question with more information, yes all the tables, their contents . Formated in a way that make sense, according to their associations

Comment: Have you tried nesting your `.includes` like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24397716/5113832) shows?

Comment: I'm curious, what is the reason is you want to load the **entire** database? Is it perhaps to use as a JSON object on the front-end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so the thing was: includes were working fine

It's just when you include and run .order or .count it still queries the database for some reason I substituted .count to .size and .order to .sort