# Ruby on Rails - Joins models for getting notifications

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, join, model, controller

In my application I have models `User`, `Post`, `Notification`, `PostShare` & `SocialPage`.

*This is how I've my models associations:*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :social_pages
  has_many :posts


class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :post_shares
  has_many :notifications
  belongs_to :user


class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post


class PostShare < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :social_page


class SocialPage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :post_shares
```

When `notifications` are added, I'm adding `post_id` to my table.

What I want to achieve is, based on the `post_id` from `notifications`, I want to find `post_shares` for that `post_id` & find the `social_pages_id` & based `social_page_id` find which user has *own/created* the page and show them notifications.

I've tried with `joins` like `Notification.joins(:post).group(:post_id).select(:post_id)`, but I don't get anything correct.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Rails nested includes or nested joins on ActiveRecord will solve your problem here

[Rails - Nested includes on Active Records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397640/rails-nested-includes-on-active-records)

You can do something like this

```
notifications = Notification.includes(post: [:user, post_shares: [social_page: :user]]).where(post_id: your_post_id)
```

OR

```
notifications = Notification.joins(post: [post_shares: [social_page: :user]]).where(post_id: your_post_id)
```

And then you can access post & social page users like this

```
post_user = notifications.map(&:post).map(&:user)

post_shares = []
notifications.each do |n|
  post_shares += n.post.post_shares
end

social_page_users = post_shares.map(&:social_page).map(&:user)
```