# Search with associations - Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three tables that are associated, I need to get all the data from my TransactionSara table through the associations.
I need all the data in my Event table to get all the data in my Table Assistant and then get all the data from my table TransactionSara

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transaction_saras, through: :assistants
end

class Assistant < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :transaction_saras, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :event
end

class TransactionSara < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assistant
end
```

I tried to solve it with this

```
Event.all.each do |event|
  event.assistants.transaction_saras
end
```

but I get an error:

```
undefined method `transaction_saras' for 
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

Any idea how I can do this search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are already multiple answers on SO for this, you need to include the associated models so you can have the associated records when you iterate through them,

```
Event.includes(assistants: :transaction_saras).all.each do |event|
  p event.assistants # this will be a list of assistants for that event
  p event.assistants.first.transaction_saras.first
end
```

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397640/rails-nested-includes-on-active-records)

You can read up on Activerecord associations on [rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: How can I get the data from transaction_sara?

Comment: that query should load both the associations for you, have a look at my edit

Comment: glad to be of help