# In Rails 5, can I construct a scope to get fields of my relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, ruby-on-rails-5, finder

I want to derive a field from a series of relations in my Rails 5 application (I want to know all the possible uniform colors associated with a player).  I have these models ...

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    belongs_to :team, :optional => true


class Team < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    has_many :uniforms, :dependent => :destroy


class Uniform < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    has_many :colors, :dependent => :nullify
```

I want to get all colors associated with the Player model, so I constructed this scope ...

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
...
  scope :with_colors, lambda {
    joins(:team => { :uniforms => :resolutions })
  }
```

However, when I construct an object and attempt to reference the derived field with my scope, I get a method undefined error ...

```
[12] pry(main)> p.with_colors
NoMethodError: undefined method `with_colors' for #<Player:0x00007fa5ab881f50>
```

What's the proper way to access the field?

Comment: An includes would work better in this case. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24397716/5671433

Comment: Your scope is defined in `Player` but `p` is `Players`.

Comment: @MoizMansur, I notice in that answer the "includes" is applied at the class level (Event), but I wish to derive my data from the specific instance.  Maybe I wasn't looking at the proper part of your link?

Comment: You can always add the query `.find_by(id: id)` at the end of the includes. Although this would give you a nested object with player data and uniform data which you might not be looking for. What @Yshmarov is a better option and more rails like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The models should look like:

```
class Player < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    belongs_to :team, :optional => true


class Team < ApplicationRecord
    ...
    has_many :players
    has_many :colors, through: :uniforms
    has_many :uniforms, :dependent => :destroy


class Uniform < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :team
    has_many :colors, :dependent => :nullify

class Color < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :uniform
```

Note that the Team `has_many :colors, through: :uniforms`. This way you can just call `@player.team.colors` and get all the available colors that uniforms of a team have.

More details on `has_many through` https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Thanks, although in my particular case, it is not an option to add "has_many :players" to my Team model.  How would I reference the colors keeping my models as I have them?

Comment: why is it "not an option to add "has_many :players" to my Team model"? That is very strange